# How to retrieve values from a node in firebase and display in a recycler view?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

```
 - Orders
        |-1234567898(phoneno)
                   |-march13,202117:33:52PM(orderid)
                                           |-name
                                           |-address
                                           |-phoneno
                                           |-orderid
        |-1231231231(phoneno)
                   |-march10,202117:33:52PM(orderid)
                                           |-name
                                           |-address
                                           |-phoneno
                                           |-orderid
        |-1212121212(phoneno)
                   |-march9,20211:33:52PM(orderid)
                                           |-name
                                           |-address
                                           |-phoneno
                                           |-orderid
```

I need to display all orders in a recycler view with values name, phoneno.

How can i get the phoneno s?

Comment: What have you tried so far in code?

Answer (score 0):

Several issues in one question . It is quite impossible to have a complete answer in one go .I would advise you to create custom class like Order for example with all data mandatory .Then if you just need to display all orders , i don t think the database structure is the best . You could have Orders:order  (with id inside the order class) , or orderBy customerID if you need to handle researches